# Dynamically set active menu item using data-toggle

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have a menu which is included in file A and B. I don't want any of my tabs to be active at first but after clicking on them I want to set the correct list item's class="active". I thought that the code below would do it. What do I need to add or change?

```
<ul id="navbar_menu" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">B</a></li>
        </ul>
```

FYI: I have included the following for the HTML page (do I need anything more than this):

```
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

According to Bootstrap's documentation (under the title "Markup"), you are still missing some HTML.

So this is mostly right, except we need the a link's `href` to point to an id of your actual tab, and not just a hash mark `#`.

```
<ul id="navbar_menu" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">A</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">B</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then we need the actual tabs to be created.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab1">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">...</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I copy pasted this code and nothing happens. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Are you certain that your reference to bootstrap is added correctly? For example, are you using other bootstrap-specific classes for your elements? If so, are they rendering correctly?

Comment: @FilipEriksson I just noticed something: Make sure you have your proper references. Add `<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` inside your `<head>` tag and `<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` at the bottom of your `<body>` tag. You need both for this to work.

Comment: I did that as well but it still doesn't work. It's really good that you pointed that out though. Do you have more ideas?

Comment: @FilipEriksson Bootstrap's javascript library requires jQuery, so maybe you could try getting a script for that too. Try putting `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` directly above the bootstrap `<script>` tag.

Comment: And if it still fails, then try adding `https:` to the beginning of the `link` and `script` url's, right before `//maxcdn......`.

Comment: It worked even without adding https. The jquery library was the key. Thanks. This menu is included in page A and B. It is great that it changes to the correct tab on click but I also want to redirect to that Particular page. How do I fix that?

Comment: FYI: The following doesn't seem to be needed: <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab1">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">...</div>
</div>

Comment: I'll ask separately regarding the navigation to another page in order to avoid confusion.  Thanks!